# Memory management in flex programs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am a flex programmer but i had nothing to do for  handle manage memory in my projects. I think lack of memory management is reason for loading lag of swf file. Can any one help me to how to handle manage memory in flex/ as3 codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most problematic uses of memory is not removing event listeners when you don't need them anymore.

For instance

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
```

When you're done with that button, remove the event listener so the owner of "doSomething" can be garbage collected. When you add an event listener to button, the owner of "doSomething"'s reference count is +1'ed. Everytime you remove an event listener you -1 that reference count. To be garbage collected, the reference count has to be zero'd.

You can let the flash player do this for you (in most cases) by using weak-referenced event listeners, like so:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething, false, 0, true);
```

Here are some more tips to help your memory management: http://blog.skinkers.com/2010/10/08/memory-management-in-air-as3-flash-garbage-collection/

And if you want to learn about the garbage collector in detail, here's a fantastic resource: http://jpauclair.net/2009/12/23/tamarin-part-iii-current-garbage-collector-in-flash-10-0/

Comment: If my answer suits your needs, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: This is partially true, since the GC use other mechanisms (such as detection of circular references) to flag instances as no longer needed.

Comment: Valid point, but in general, this is the most common usecase.

Comment: Loremplpsum, do u have any idea about GC used in flash programming

Comment: pls check www.pixlr.com . Im excited bcoz this apps take very few time for loading. we should confused whether it is swf or not. it is perfect programming with memory handling. Please share your informations. Thanks

Comment: If your simple talking about loading-time, filesize is the major factor. Get your swf and all loaded resources as lightweight as possible, that's what reduces loading time.

Comment: The answer is actually backward. When you remove the event listener, you allow the object that owns "doSomething" to be garbage collected, _not_ button.  cHECK OUT http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html

Comment: you're right. I knew that, but mixed it up in my explanation. I'll edit.. :)